# pandas remove values within a rolling time window

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame whose index is time, and column is either 1 or 0(1 indicating some signal). Once I got a signal, I want to remove the 1s within the next 5 seconds. e.g:

from

```
2023-08-16 23:59:10,0
2023-08-16 23:59:11,1 # got a signal at 11th second
2023-08-16 23:59:12,1 # remove this 1 at 12th second
2023-08-16 23:59:13,0 # unchanged
2023-08-16 23:59:14,1 # remove this 1 at 14 second
2023-08-16 23:59:15,1 # remove this 1 at 15 second
2023-08-16 23:59:16,0 # unchanged 
2023-08-16 23:59:17,0
2023-08-16 23:59:18,0  
2023-08-16 23:59:19,1 # got a new signal at 19th second
2023-08-16 23:59:20,0 
2023-08-16 23:59:21,1 # remove this 1 at 21 second
2023-08-16 23:59:22,0
```

to

```
2023-08-16 23:59:10,0
2023-08-16 23:59:11,1 # got a signal at 11th second
2023-08-16 23:59:12,0 
2023-08-16 23:59:13,0 
2023-08-16 23:59:14,0 
2023-08-16 23:59:15,0 
2023-08-16 23:59:16,0 
2023-08-16 23:59:17,0
2023-08-16 23:59:18,0  
2023-08-16 23:59:19,1 # got a new signal at 19th second
2023-08-16 23:59:20,0 
2023-08-16 23:59:21,0 
2023-08-16 23:59:22,0
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is one of those cases in which you cannot easily vectorize.

Using a loop:

```
out = []
last = pd.NaT
for idx, val in zip(df.index, df['col']):
    if val == 1:
        if not ((idx-last)<pd.Timedelta('5s')):
            last = idx
            out.append(1)
            continue
    out.append(0)
        
df['new'] = out
```

Output:

```
                     col  new
2023-08-16 23:59:10    0    0
2023-08-16 23:59:11    1    1
2023-08-16 23:59:12    1    0
2023-08-16 23:59:13    0    0
2023-08-16 23:59:14    1    0
2023-08-16 23:59:15    1    0
2023-08-16 23:59:16    0    0
2023-08-16 23:59:17    0    0
2023-08-16 23:59:18    0    0
2023-08-16 23:59:19    1    1
2023-08-16 23:59:20    0    0
2023-08-16 23:59:21    1    0
2023-08-16 23:59:22    0    0
```